# Why won't a gif hosted from my website work on the Facebook timeline?

Tags: facebook, share, gif

I am trying to share a gif hosted from my website, but for some reason it will not work on the Facebook timeline (it will just serve up a link). I then began searching through Google and pasting in gifs from many other sites and they all worked (giphy, buzzfeed, techcrunch, etc). The gif itself is [Keep Avocados Green](http://www.olivarioliveoil.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/KEEP-AVOCADOS-GREEN_CC_v03.gif) and is public.

Comment: Look at those sites og-tags

Comment: @WizKid I did, and wrote a conditional script to serve up the og:image as the gif if the page had one. Still the gif isn't playing.

Comment: You are sure that that is what they are doing?